# c# custom serialization and deserialize simple class

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, text-files

i have this class

```
class MyClass{
   int x;
   byte[] arr;
}
```

I want to serialize it to text file but on custom way.

I want before I write the `x` value i want to write : the x value is: x.

and to do some manipulate on the arr (like +1 on every value) and move tab.

and then " the value again is" the value of X "have a nice day" with tab

how can i serialize like this to txt file,

and how can i deserialize from txt file like that to MyClass?

for example: x=4, arr={1,2,3}
the txt file will be

```
the value of X is: 4
   arr is: 2,3,4
    the value again is:5 have a nice day
```

how can i do this please?
i don't want to do special Get property for that var , because on my program i use this Get .

Answer (score 1):

Serializing is different than what you are trying to do, but if you want special formatted output, some would do an override of the ToString() method, but you can just create another method something like...

```
    public string textOutput()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("the value of X is: {0}\r\n   arr is: ", x);
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", i == 0 ? "" : ", ", arr[i]);

        // don't know where your 5 value is coming from though... but place-holdered it
        sb.AppendFormat("\r\n      the value again is: {0} have a nice day", 5);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

and write your output as needed.  Or you could create this as its own getter property and that too.